# Irrecvdemo program in or remote library gives fatal error #include<WProgram.h>

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, remote-control

Whenever I compile irrecvdemo of or remote library it gives error saying that fatal error saying

> no file or directory exists `#include <WProgram.h>`

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! It sounds like you've got a syntax error in your sketch. If you include your code it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: #include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

You are using a very old library on a modern IDE.  The file that was called `WProgram.h` in IDE version 0023 and below is now called `Arduino.h`.  You will need to change any references to `WProgram.h` to `Arduino.h` instead.

Well written libraries do this with a #ifdef block:

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
# include <Arduino.h>
#else
# include <WProgram.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Can I know exactly where to edit and which lib file

Comment: I can't really tell you that, no, you will have to find it for yourself. You will need to find where you installed the library to and look in the files included with it. There may be only 2 - a .cpp and a .h file - or there may be more. There may be a "utility" folder with more in as well. The include will always be near the top of the files though, so it should be easy to spot. Depending on your operating system you may have the facility to search for files with certain words in them - for instance on Linux and OS X there is the `grep` command line utility. Not sure what is on Windows.

Comment: I found those files and copied that codes which you gave,I tried on CCP file h file...I tried all combinations and used older version of ide also but it did not compile...

Comment: @AdithyaPai What is the library you are trying to use?

Comment: IR remote library... Just using demo codes to get binary numbers from normal ir remote...by connecting ir receiver sensor tsop-...

Comment: @AdithyaPai ***WHAT*** IR remote library? Give me a link to it.

Comment: https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C5785360335

Comment: Well, that library already has all the right things in it and doesn't require any modification. Your code compiles against it perfectly. My guess is that you have a second, rather ancient, copy somewhere around that is conflicting. Search your hard drive for any old copy and eradicate it.